# Suppose $\mu(X)=1$ and $f, g $are nonnegative function such that $fg \geq 1$ a.e. prove $(\int fd\mu)(\int gd\mu) \geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have a problem in $L^p$ space. Suppose $\mu(X)=1$ and $f, g $are nonnegative function such that $fg \geq 1$ a.e. prove $(\int fd\mu)(\int gd\mu) \geq 1$.

I have no any idea to prove that.  Holder inequality? thanks

Comment: What is "a.e."?

Comment: almost everywhere

Comment: You can also use Jensen's Inequality to show that $(\int 1/f)(\int f) \geq 1$, and then use the fact that $(\int g\cdot f \cdot 1/f)(\int f) \geq (\int 1/f)( \int f) \geq 1$.

Comment: You are right, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, you have
$$\left(\int \sqrt{f}^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \int \sqrt{g}^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \geq \int \sqrt{fg} \geq \int 1 = 1$$

So, squaring both sides, you get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the square root of the inequality gives $$\sqrt f \sqrt g \geq 1.$$ can you see how to proceed?

Comment: why is $\leq$? And how to proceed?

Comment: I don't see how if $fg \geq 1$ you have $\sqrt{fg}\leq 1$

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was wrong about the inequality. If you take the square root of both sides in the original inequality you get the other one.

Comment: thank you for your advice, everyone

Answer (score 0):

Holder's inequality says $|fg|_1\leq |f|_p|g|_q$, where $p$ and $q$ are Holder conjugates, that is, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Well, when $p=q=2$, we see $\int fg d\mu\leq \sqrt{\int f^2 d\mu}\sqrt{\int g^2d\mu}\leq\int f^2d\mu\int g^2d\mu$, which is very close to what we want, but we will instead need $\int fd\mu\int g d\mu$, so we use Holder's on $|\sqrt{f}\sqrt{g}|$ to get $\int \sqrt{fg}d\mu\leq\sqrt{\int \sqrt{f}^2d\mu\int\sqrt{g}^2d\mu}=\sqrt{\int f d\mu \int g d\mu}$, noticing on the left we have $\int\sqrt{fg}d\mu\geq\int \sqrt{1}d\mu=\int1d\mu=1$, thus together we have $1\leq\sqrt{\int fd\mu \int gd\mu}$, thus squaring both sides shows us $1\leq\int fd\mu\int gd\mu$.